# ABIEncoderV2PackedStorage bug, is something to worry about? any info?

Tags: solidity, bug, compiler

I have a simple factory of ERC-20 Tokens, deployed to Rinkeby using remix.

When I create contracts with this factory and verify the code in Etherscan (using etherscan API) I am having this warning in Etherscan:

> Warning: The compiled contract might be susceptible to
>   ABIEncoderV2PackedStorage (low-severity) Solidity Compiler Bugs.

Sample here:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x55D65C01E8D445D166eE50Cf6076015d2F7Bd46e#code

Etherscan shows a broken link to the *ABIEncoderV2PackedStorage* bug

And I haven't seen any bug report about this ABIEncoderV2PackedStorage thing.

I this something I should worry about?

Any link or report about this bug in solidity?

Thanks

Comment: https://blog.ethereum.org/2019/03/26/solidity-optimizer-and-abiencoderv2-bug/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if "low severity" conveys the right message. You might be affected and that might be very serious, or you might not be affected in which case it's inconsequential.

It depends on what your contract is doing.

https://blog.ethereum.org/2019/03/26/solidity-optimizer-and-abiencoderv2-bug/

In theory, if your units tests passed on the bytecode you deployed and your testing suite was thorough then it would catch anomalous results, or convincingly demonstrate that it works as designed.

Hope it helps.